# Is there an easy formula for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory

It is the sequence which represents the maximum number of cycles in an undirected graph with n nodes, n>=3. These graphs have all nodes connected to every other node.

How would I count the number of cycles in such a complete graph.

Also is there was a formula to this sequence to find the number of cycles with n nodes. Bonus points if you can find the name of this sequence if one exists. Thanks!

Comment: The only match in OEIS is [A053731](http://oeis.org/A053731), which is $\left\lceil \frac 18 \left(_{(n+5)}C_8\right) \right\rceil$

Comment: Aren't $(1234)$ and $(1324)$ different cycles in $K_4$?

Comment: The sequence as you have it is just $A_{n}=2^n-1-\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$, but I don't think it's right.

Comment: mjqxxxx you are right, I don't think I am counting all the cycles. But then how would I count them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition we have for the number $Q_n$ of cycles in a labelled copy of $K_n$ that
$$Q_n = \sum_{k=3}^n {n\choose k}\frac{k!}{2k}.$$
This gives the sequence
$$1, 7, 37, 197, 1172, 8018, 62814, 556014, 5488059, 59740609,\ldots$$
which is number [A002807](http://oeis.org/A002807) at the OEIS.